# Draw a circle with half fill color

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uibezierpath

I have to implement circle with half fill color. I found 3rd parties api but I don't want to use them. Is there any way to draw circle without third Party. I want like this : http://justpaste.it/jv07

Comment: Watch `WWDC 2014: What's New in Interface Builder`. It has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This draws a semi circle with half fill in swift 4.2

```
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
shape.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), radius: 50, startAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: false)
shape.path = path.cgPath
```

[image]

For more info
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-bezierpathwitharccenter

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get that effect. Probably the easiest way is to make the gray circle, and then the partial arc on top of it.

A useful paradigm for drawing is to think of each area as a separate thing, set up in layers. The order you draw things is the order they show up, from back to front.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAShapeLayer strokeEnd property for partial oval stroke.

```
        CAShapeLayer * oval3 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        oval3.frame              = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        oval3.fillColor          = nil;
        oval3.strokeColor        = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        oval3.lineWidth          = 13;
        oval3.strokeEnd          = 0.6;
        UIBezierPath*  oval3Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:oval3.bounds];
        oval3.path = oval3Path.CGPath;
```